# Why are there two verbs in this sentence? (A raid ... starting late on Wednesday yielded as much as 20 tonnes...)

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, subordinate-clauses

I want to know why they have used two verbs in this sentence 
I think that the usage of a conjunction is missing.

> A night-long raid at an ice factory in Rajabazar starting late on Wednesday yielded as much as 20 tonnes of carcass meat, packed and ready to be sold.

Can this be possible?

> A night long raid at an ice factory in Rajabazar starting late on Wednesday WHICH yielded...

[image: picture of a newspaper column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**starting late on Wednesday** is a subordinate clause headed by the present participle.  **starting** is not a tensed (finite) verb. The tensed verb in that sentence is **yielded**.

> The outdoor concert, **featuring the Irish rock band U2**, was cancelled
>   because of inclement weather.